# Selenium Wire Logs Empty

Tags: java, selenium, tomcat, logging, classloader

We recently switched our project to be more modular.

We are using selenium with jbrowserdriver to scrape data from a page.

We are using Spring Boot with Tomcat.

Previously, we had a single war file that we deployed to tomcat with all of our class files packaged up.  We were using jbrowserdriver with wire logs to capture headers during a session and it worked well.

However, we have now separated out some of our functionality and it appears we are running afowl of differing classloader issues in tomcat.

Our system is laid out like this:

```
/companyDir
+ -- /libs
| + -- core.jar
| + -- /widgets
| | + -- widgetA.jar
| | + -- widgetB.jar
```

Tomcat is configured to include /libs/*.jar and /libs/widgets/*.jar in its shared.loader property.  These jar files are included at tomcat start.

We then deploy a file project.war which has the Spring dependencies and the controller endpoint.

However, now when we call the endpoint and the endpoint executes widgetA.jar, the wire logs are completely empty.  We see the wire logs show up in catalina.out, but the call `driver.manage().logs().get("wire")` shows up empty.  I'm not sure exactly how to configure this so that the internal logs in our webdriver are filled with the wire logs that we are obviously getting back.

I may just be fuzzy on the classloader issues as that appears to be the problem.

Comment: So deeper digging reveals that the wire logs are still being generated by org.apache.http but when `LogsServer.java` executes `updateSettings()` to redirect/reroute `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` to `com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.WireLog`, this is not working as it does when all classes are executed from the same classloader.  As jbrowserdriver uses RMI for its execution I'm having a little trouble understanding how this even works normally, although it still appears to be an issue related to classLoaders.

Comment: Additional information: I have modified the structure so that instead of using tomcat's shared.loader property, I am now using the application context to specify the jars I want to include mapped to /WEB-INF/lib.  Same result.

I believe that rules out a classloader issue and points to it being run from the external jar only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by using Context Resources, we were able to re-capture the logs.

In /src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml for the project.war that is being deployed, we can specify a "JarResources" resource and make the jars available to the same classloader.  Tada, problem solved.

Here's the layout for the context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/ourApp" docBase="/ourApp">
    <Resources>
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/path/to/our/configFiles/"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <JarResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/path/to/our/jars/libs"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <JarResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
            base="/path/to/our/jars/libs/widgets"
            webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" />
    </Resources>
</Context>
```